# Creating DecoupledEditor passing textarea as parameter

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I'm trying to use DecoupledEditor to replace a textarea in a form I have.

The [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-decoupled_decouplededitor-DecoupledEditor.html#static-function-create) show that I can just pass the element that I want to replace with the editor and then append the toolbar to the DOM.

The problem is that when I pass a textarea element as a parameter, the editor does not work properly. I can't type more than 1 line in it for example. When I pass a div instead, it works perfectly.

Previously, when I was using the ClassicEditor build and it worked normally when passing a textarea as parameter.

Is this a bug or is it simply expected behavior not shown in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a `<textarea>` to the [`DecoupledEditor`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-decoupled_decouplededitor-DecoupledEditor.html). Only [`ClassicEditor`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html) can replace a `<textarea>`.

Passing a normal element differs from passing a `<textarea>`. A normal element (e.g. a `<div>`) can be **turned into** an editor. The editor is initialized on it. If you pass a `<textarea>` to the `ClassicEditor` the behaviour is different – the classic editor hides that `<textarea>` (via setting `display:none`), loads data from it and adds its main UI element right after that `<textarea>`. `DecoupledEditor` can't do that.